# javascript convert decimal to date

Tags: javascript, date, decimal

I have a date as a string:
`var mydate = "05/05/2011"`
when I pass this var to a function like:
`myfunction(mydate);`

I alert the results and get a decimal not the string date:

```
function myfunction(mydate){
    alert(mydate);
}
```

produces :

> 0.0004972650422675286

how do I get it back to a date?

Comment: Please use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: Thats the result of the mathematical expression: 5 / 5 / 2011 = 4.972e-4 sure the string is quoted?

Comment: There has to be more to this, in your example calling myfunction() and passing it a string would just alert the string. *Ninja Edit* Nice catch Alex, that appears to be what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem as well (I was passing the string from codebehind on a popup to a javascript on the opener).  My solution was pretty simple.

in asp.net

```
<asp:Label ID="foo" runat="server"/>
```

in javascript

```
foo.Text = "5/5/2011";
```

in codebehind:

```
string runThis = "blahblah"
+ "'"
+ foo.Text
+ "';";
```

Without the single-quote surrounding the text it would spit out the decimal jibberish (ie the mathematical result of 5 / 5 / 2011)

I'm guessing in your situation you could do

```
alert("'" + myDate + "'");
```

Answer (score 4):

Thats the result of the mathematical expression: `5 / 5 / 2011 = 4.972e-4`, ensure the string is quoted.

```
var x = 5/5/2011; //performs division

as opposed to

var x = "5/5/2011"; //creates a string
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this syntax:

```
var mydate  = new Date("05/05/2011");
```

Answer (score 0):

05 divided by 05 divided by 2011 is 0.0004972650422675286, so my guess is it's thinking that 05/05/2011 is an expression not a string. Are you sure there are quotes wrapped around the variable?

Comment: Actually the date is contained already in a variable as a string, This why I'm not sure why it tried to solve the equation when I pass the variable containing the date already as a string to another function...

Answer (score 0):

0.0004972650422675286 is `5 / 5 / 2011` (as in division).

It is likely you are typing your date without quoting the string, or you are passing the string to `eval` when you should be passing it to [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).